# Circular Dependency when compile with Kotlin 1.1.2-4, but not on 1.1.2-3

Tags: android, kotlin

I got the below error

```
* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:compileProductionDebugKotlin
\--- :app:kaptProductionDebugKotlin
     \--- :app:compileProductionDebugKotlin (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

When I use Kotlin version 1.1.2-4 (okay when I use 1.1.2-3).

In my app build.gradle I have the following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

When I remove `kotlin-kapt`, it compiles fine.

Did I do anything wrong, or this is a Kotlin bug?

Comment: Was fixed in 1.1.2-5. Happened to me  on *-4 and solved after downgrading to -3.

Answer (score 1):

Tested worked well when move to Kotlin version 1.1.2-5. Thanks @AntonKazakov!

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17936 seems using Android studio v3 can fix it too

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 3.0 (canary 4) already. The problem exist here when compile with 1.1.2-4